# Enable TextBox depending on enum value

Tags: wpf, binding, enums

I have a TextBox that I want to enable if a `Order`'s Status is either `OrderStatus.New` or `OrderStatus.Ordered`. It it's something else, the TextBox should stay disabled.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding OrderedAmount}" IsEnabled="True"/>
```

I assume I need to use some kind of MultiBinding, but cannot seem to find a proper resource on how to do that in this particular case.

Comment: Just bind `IsEnabled` to the `OrderStatus` and use a converter to return `true` or `false` depending what the enum value is.

Comment: Hi, You could create a `style` that uses a `DataTrigger` which could set the `textbox` value to be enabled. Take a look at this thread; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211264/why-cant-i-use-a-datatrigger-to-set-textbox-isenabled-true Hope it helps!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a ValueConverter for this:

```
public class IsNewOrOrderedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        OrderStatus status = (OrderStatus)value;
        return status == OrderStatus.New || status == OrderStatus.Ordered;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then use it as the converter in your xaml:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding OrderedAmount}" 
          IsEnabled="{Binding OrderStatus, Converter={StaticResource IsNewOrOrderedConverter}"/>
```

Don't forget to declare the resource:

```
 <App.Resources>
    <myPrefix:IsNewOrOrderedConverter x:Key="IsNewOrOrderedConverter" />
 </App.Resources>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx on declaring resources.

**Parametrization**

A single converter can be made parametrized so it can be reused for different order types.
The XAML would be like this:

```
        <local:OrderStatusToBooleanConverter 
               StatusList="New,Ordered"  x:Key="NewOrOrderedConverter" />
        <local:OrderStatusToBooleanConverter 
               StatusList="Delivered"  x:Key="DeliveredConverter" />
```

This requires some special tactics since there is no way by default to make it readable (with enum values separated by a comma). That's where we need a type converter:

```
public class StringToOrderStatusArrayConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string);
    }
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return new OrderStatus[0];
        }
        else
        {
            return (from s in value.ToString().Split(',')
                    select Enum.Parse(typeof(OrderStatus), s))
                    .OfType<OrderStatus>()
                    .ToArray<OrderStatus>();

        }
    }
}
```

The type converter converts the input string array of enum values separated by a comma into an array.

This array can then be fed into the `ValueConverter`:

```
public class OrderStatusToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    [TypeConverter(typeof(StringToOrderStatusArrayConverter))]
    public OrderStatus[] StatusList { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        OrderStatus status = (OrderStatus)value;
        return StatusList != null && StatusList.Contains(status);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer! If I have an another TextBox called DeliveredAmount which is otherwise similar but should be enabled when OrderStatus is Delivered, do I need to create another Converter or can I somehow check for the field in question inside the Converter? I.e. does the Converter know which field it's converting for?

Comment: @TatuUlmanen It would need a new converter since the convert only knows the value it is given, not what it is for, and there won't be a way to distinguish a New Order from a Delivered Order.

Comment: @TatuUlmanen I have updated my answer to include working with parameters, this is a bit more complex however.