# Binding to simple properties in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've got a problem binding to a property on my model. In a DataGrid, I'm displaying Errors. Each error has the property `ErrorDescription` which itself has the property `Severity`.

I can bind to `Severity` in the TextColumn of my DataGrid below, however binding to `Severity` in the TemplateColumn fails with the error

> "Cannot resolve property "ErrorDescription" in data context of type
>   MainViewModel"

**The DataContext my image-column is not the same as in my first text-column. Why is that?**

```
  <DataGrid ItemsSource ="{Binding Errors}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            // works
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ErrorDescription.Severity}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image>
                            <Image.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Image">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                       // Binding fails
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ErrorDescription.Severity}" Value="Unknown">
                                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/error.jpg"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        // Binding fails
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ErrorDescription.Severity}" Value="Ok">
                                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/ok.jpg"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Image.Style>
                        </Image>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
      </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a Converter instead of DataTrigger?
When I want to show icons or specific property values depending an enum I do it with a Converter.

The Converter would be similar to this:

```
public class ErrorSeverityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Severity severity = (Severity)value;
        switch(severity)
        {
            case Severity.Unknown:
                return "/error.jpg";

            case Severity.Ok:
                return "/ok.jpg";
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

There is this other question that is very similar even if not on a DataGridTemplateColumn

[Enable TextBox depending on enum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320781/enable-textbox-depending-on-enum-value)

Comment: Severity is indeed an enum, however, I can display its value in the TextColumn without any further ado, but I cannot use get its value in the TemplateColumn. I'll adjust my post.